# how to set the text and image in particular item textview and imageview in horizontal listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have passed the value from fragment to mainactivity while click the button in fragment class. my main activity have one fragment and one horizontal listview with base adapter.my  horizontal listview have one imageview and one textview. i want to set the value and image in particular horizontal listitem. if i have to click the first item plus button in fragment class the value and image want to set first item of horizontal listview. please suggest me.my horizontal listview adapter code here. thanks in advance.`

```
public class HorizontalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
int value = 0;
int a[];

public HorizontalAdapter(Context c, int value) {
    context = c;
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        // convertView = new View(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizantal_image, null);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    // imageView.setImageResource(image);
    System.out.println(value);
    System.out.println(position);
    System.out.println(convertView);
    System.out.println(parent);
    // textView.setText(dataObjects[position]);
    // imageView.setImageResource(imageid[position]);

    return convertView;

}
```

}

Comment: What is your problem? You want to communicate to your adapter from the activity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Pass some array of object or ArrayList According to your requirement and change the value of specific item of array and pass that to your adapter. You can create one Model Class in which you can define text and image like this

```
 public class ListModel{
        private String imageUrl;
        private String title;

        public String getImageUrl() {
            return imageUrl;
        }

        public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
```

And inside your BaseAdapter you have to use ArrayList of ListModel like this:

```
ArrayList<ListModel> listData = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
```

And you have to set content of listData from some where like this

```
ListModel listModelData = new ListModel();
// Add Content for specific object
listModelData.setTitle("your title");
listModelData.setImageUrl("your image url");


// Add this object in listview 
listData.add(listModelData);
```

After that you have to pass this list in your BaseAdapter like this:

```
public class HorizontalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private  int value = 0;
private ArrayList<ListModel> listData;

public HorizontalAdapter(Context c, int value, ArrayList<ListModel>   listData) {
    context = c;
    this.value = value;
   this.listData= listData;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        // convertView = new View(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horizantal_image, null);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getImageUrl()));
    // imageView.setImageResource(image);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getTitle()));
    System.out.println(position);
    System.out.println(convertView);
    System.out.println(parent);
    if (listData.get(position).getImageUrl()!=null){
      imageView.setImageResource(listData.get(position).getImageUrl());
    }

    if (listData.get(position).getTitle()!=null){
       textView.setText(listData.get(position).getTitle());
    }



    return convertView;

}
}
```

And to update specific position of ArrayList you have to do this:

```
listData.get(0).setImageUrl("Updated Image url");
listData.get(0).setTitle("Updated Title ");
```

And to set the adapter in your listview you have to do this from your activity:

```
HorizontalAdapter  mAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter (mCtx, value,listData );
mListViews.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And  to update the Listview you have to call notifyDataSetChanged after updating the content of ArrayList like this:

```
if (mAdapter !=null){
mAdapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```